# How can I write an addresses array field when interacting with the contract?

Tags: solidity

I am facing an issue. I have the following function in my smartcontract :

```
function addWhitelists(address[] memory _users) external onlyOwner {
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _users.length; i++) 
        addWhitelist(_users[i]);     
}
```

The idea of this function is to be able to whitelist a batch of ethereum addresses with one transaction. However, I don't understand how I should write the addresses in etherscan/myetherwallet field to interact with the smartcontract (which format should I use)?

Answer (score 1):

In etherscan you can interact with the smart contract method by passing this line in the field:

`["0xDeadDeAddeAddEAddeadDEaDDEAdDeaDDeAD0001","0xDeadDeAddeAddEAddeadDEaDDEAdDeaDDeAD0002","0xDeadDeAddeAddEAddeadDEaDDEAdDeaDDeAD0003"]`

---

Also one piece of advice - if you're going to pass hundreds of address then replace:

`for (uint256 i = 0; i < _users.length; i++)`

With:

```
uint256 _users_length = _users.length;
for (uint256 i = 0; i < _users_length; i++)
```

This will save you some gas costs, because on each iteration the loop is going to look for the length of array `_users` which is heavier operation than reading already declared variable `_users_length`.